# params in overriden function-call operator() c++

Tags: c++, oop, arguments, virtual-functions

I have come across this overridden function-call operator() inside a IonizationTunnel.h file:

```
void operator()(Particles *, std::vector<double>*, unsigned int,  int ipart_ref = 0) override;
```

This matches exactly with the parameters of a virtual void operator() inside a Ionization.h file:

```
virtual void operator()(Particles *, std::vector<double>*, unsigned int,  int ipart_ref = 0) {}
```

Ionization is the Base class. IonizationTunnel is the Derived class.

2 questions:

1. What does a parameter with no-name inside the argument list mean? I.e. the pointer to a Particles object, **Particles***. Or the **unsigned int** without a name. Why do they appear like that and what do they mean?
2. What does the parameter with a name (so an usual parameter) being set to a value inside () mean?
   I.e. **int ipart_ref = 0**. Does it mean that when we'll call IonizationTunnelObject.operator()(arguments) we have to specify 3 arguments and not 4, the last argument (ipart_ref) being silently inferred to be 0 even if not written in the 3 arguments we specify? Or can we call IonizationTunnelObject.operator()(arguments) using 4 arguments and set ipart_ref to any integer value we want?

I am accustomed to seeing foo(int x) {code} and I have never seen foo(int) {code}.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: In the declaration of the function, the name of the variable is ignored and just there for readability. Apart from simple habit, a common reason to leave it away is the following: If your have overloaded functions which don't use one of the parameters, you can leave away the name in the implementation as well to make it clear to the user that the variable is not used. Moreover, this avoids warnings from the compiler about unused variables.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unused parameter that does not necessarily need a name can be useful sometimes to let overload resolution pick the desired overload:

```
void foo(int) {
    std::cout << "this is foo(int)\n";
    std::cout << "I dont need a name for the argument, because I am not using it anyhow";
}
void foo(double) {
    std::cout << "this is foo(double)";
}

foo(1);   // calls foo(int)
foo(1.0); // calls foo(double)
```

However, what you see is probably just the names omitted on the declaration and on the definition they will be given names, as in:

```
void foo(int);          // forward declaration
void bar(int x) {
    if (x==42) foo(x);  // needs a declaration of foo
}
void foo(int x) {       // definition
    if (x!=42) bar(x);
}
```

The `= something` is default arguments. A function

```
void foo(int x = 0) {
    std::cout << x;
}
```

Can be called either like this:

```
foo(42);
```

or like this:

```
foo();
```

in which case it is equivalent to calling

```
foo(0);
```

Comment: Small clarification : What @largest_prime_is_463035 means is that overloading is a reason to have an input variable that you don't need. Having a name or not doesn't change anything about the overloading itself.

Comment: Thank you very much to you two! Much appreciated!